# Render React JS component with Javascript

Tags: asp.net, reactjs

I am using javascript to render React Component.

Javascript snippet

```js
function loadRemoteComponent(url) {
    return fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(source => {
            var exports = {}
            function require(name) {               
                if (name == 'react') return React
                else throw `You can't use modules other than "react" in remote component.`
            }
            const transformedSource = Babel.transform(source, {
                presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-2']
            }).code
            eval(transformedSource)
            return exports.__esModule ? exports.default : exports
        })
}
```

using URL, I am rendering React Component. 
React component is rendered using Javascript with in current solution / web site.

When I tried to render the Javascript in different web site, it shows me CORS error.

I have tried "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"; but that is not working,

It shows me error in console
"Access to fetch at 'http://xxx/Scripts/components/xxx.jsx' from origin 'http://yyy' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

Do any one have any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the cors headers to wildcard on the server side?

```
// nodejs/express
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am using ASP.NET core application. can you tell me where should I have to write this code.